# single filter for extra where in datatable

Tags: php, filter, where-clause, join, datatables-1.10

Following [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125615/single-filter-not-working-when-where-clause-have-specified-value?noredirect=1#comment75270130_44125615) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004884/how-to-join-two-tables-with-ssp-class-php). The question have answered using https://github.com/emran/ssp. But i have problem in my query below :

```
$joinQuery = "FROM `monitor` AS `a` JOIN `sym_category` AS `b` JOIN `model_cat` AS `c`";
$joinQuery.= "ON (`b`.`id_sym` = `a`.`id_sym`) AND (`c`.`id_mod` = `a`.`id_mod`)";
$extraWhere= "`a`.`id_car` LIKE 'MKT%' OR `a`.`id_car` LIKE 'RK%' OR `a`.`id_car` LIKE 'CC%'";

echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $joinQuery, $extraWhere )
);
```

ssp.class.join.php :

```
static function simple($request,$sql_details,$table,$primaryKey,$columns,$joinQuery = NULL,$extraWhere = '',$groupBy = '')
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = SSP::sql_connect( $sql_details );

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = SSP::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = SSP::order( $request, $columns, $joinQuery );
        $where = SSP::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings, $joinQuery );

        // IF Extra where set then set and prepare query
        if($extraWhere){
            $extraWhere = ($where) ? ' AND '.$extraWhere : ' WHERE '.$extraWhere;
}
        $groupBy = ($groupBy) ? ' GROUP BY '.$groupBy .' ' : '';

        // Main query to actually get the data
        if($joinQuery){
            $col = SSP::pluck($columns, 'db', $joinQuery);
            $query =  "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".implode(", ", $col)."
             $joinQuery
             $where
             $extraWhere
             $groupBy
             $order
             $limit";
        }else{
            $query =  "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".implode("`, `", SSP::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
             FROM `$table`
             $where
             $extraWhere
             $groupBy
             $order
             $limit";
        }
```

After I try to put some `$extraWhere`, the single column filter not working but the data which filtered by extra where could appear `(status 200 OK)`.

---

i have try to remove :

```
$extraWhere= "/*`a`.`id_car` LIKE 'MKT%' OR */`a`.`id_car` LIKE 'RK%' OR `a`.`id_car` LIKE 'CC%'";
```

the single column filter is working, but why it isn't working when i add filter `MKT%` in where clause?

Comment: what you get in the error log? and how you know that are not wolrking this solution?

Comment: @inye when i use all extrawhere `(include MKT%)`, table data was appear based on extrawhere `(status 200 OK)`. Then i try to filter at `id_car` column : `columns[0][search][value]:201 (status 200 OK)` . But the data not filtered.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do maybe your `$extrawhere` is no good, but a good way is `echo` the final query in the `simple` function and  then debug (see de query and compare with the query that you think you have to do)